# ADO Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, delphi

I have here Delphi 10.2.2 , and I think I might be using something incorrectly .

I have a stored procedure with following parameter  `@etikettnr nvarchar(50)`
This same procedure in Delphi has Datatype String, Size 50.

For some unknown reason if I pass to this Procedure a String from a FDQuery like this:

```
DM1.spHISTJUMBO.Parameters.ParamValues['@etikettnr']:=DM1.HISTJUMBOQueryetikettnr.AsString
```

or

```
M1.spHISTJUMBO.Parameters.ParamValues['@etikettnr']:=DM1.HISTJUMBOQueryetikettnr.Value
```

I get

> The Conversion of the nvarchar value '038843738001' overflowed an int column error.

The thing is this is a `nvarchar(50) column` and that is ok so.

I get the same error if I try it like this

```
DM1.spHISTJUMBO.Parameters.ParamValues['@etikettnr']:=038843738001
```

or this

```
DM1.spHISTJUMBO.Parameters.ParamValues['@etikettnr']:='038843738001';
```

But sometimes it gets trough without error. Why is this trying to convert ...

Any idea why?

Thank you

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spAWBAR_HISTORIE_JUMBO]
(@OP varchar(10),
 @ID int,
 @Auftnr int,
 @Pos int,
 @Menge int,
 @teile_nr int,
 @eingebaut_in int,
 @etikettnr nvarchar(50),
 @esnr int,
 @esname nvarchar(50),
 @gestell nvarchar(50),
 @gestellname nvarchar(50),
 @zustandname nvarchar(50),
 @lastmodzeit datetime2(5),
 @bearbtyp int,
 @smenge int,
 @Location nvarchar(50),
 @DB_YEAR int
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttrDm.png)

Dang I cant believe this got me again . The Stored Procedure was not the problem . The Problem was a query before. Which did this :
`DM1.SyncQuery.SQL.Add('select Auftnr from AWBAR_HISTORIE_JUMBO where Auftnr='+DM1.HISTJUMBOQueryauftnr.AsString+' and Pos='+DM1.HISTJUMBOQuerypos.AsString+' and Etikettnr='+DM1.HISTJUMBOQueryetikettnr.AsString+' and Lastmodzeit='+quotedstr(DM1.HISTJUMBOQuerylastmodzeit.AsString)+' and Location='+quotedstr('Augustdorf')+' and DB_YEAR='+inttostr(CHANGED_ARRAY[i].DB_YEAR));`

This does not work , I forgot why, but I had this problem before ...

I was told I need to do it like this :
`Qry.SQL.Add('and Gestellname=:Gestellname and Kuid= :kuid and ltrim(rtrim(Gestell)) = :email');`

and then 
`Qry.Parameters.ParamByName('Gestellname').Value := Gestellname;
                  Qry.Parameters.ParamByName('KUID').Value := Kuid;
                  Qry.Parameters.ParamByName('email').Value := email;`

The pasted example is from another program where I had the same problem :)

The problem is I think , that for some reason ADOQuery thinks this Field Etikettnr is integer , because the very first record in it is nummeric...

Srry guys... this screwed up my day. But thank you for the tips.

Comment: Please post the definition for the stored procedure

Comment: the other thing is what is the data type of `@etikettnr`

Comment: I am not sure if I did this wrong , but I manually set the Parameter Property in Delphi from WideString to String ... 

I refreshed the Procedure in Delphi it is WideString again ... seems to be working .

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the procedure column wasn't an INT when you ran this. Perhaps you thought you had refreshed / recreated it when you didn't, and then when you did the column changed. Just a thought. Also, unless you expect unicode characters, there is no need for nvarchar -- varchar would suffice.

Comment: It is not working still, I changed the Parameter in Delphi to WideString ... sometimes it inserts the 038843738001 sometimes it tries to convert.... but for no reason at all . The table itself , etikettnr is nvarchar(50)

Comment: I'll try it .. this is string field... but it contains only numbers...

Comment: [CHANGED] AWBAR_HISTORIE_JUMBO The conversion of the varchar value '038843738001' overflowed an int column
After changing in Database the Field to Varchar ... the Stored Procedure... and then altering it in Delphi ... looks like I am doing something horribly wrong, sometimes it tries to convert... but not always...it goes once ok... then maybe twice... then again error

Comment: it is true , this field was earlier int. then I changed it to nvarchar(50)...
I refreshed the ADOStoredProcedures in Delphi , there I to have now String .

But something is screwing me somewhere... becuase I just tried this :
                DM1.spHISTJUMBO.Parameters.ParamValues['@etikettnr']:=DM1.HISTJUMBOQueryetikettnr.Value+'t';

This should theoretically work because in MSSQL the Stored Procedure and the Table is varchar now ... but I get a error converting data type varchar to numeric. This is not my day :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or just

```
and Etikettnr='+quotedstr(DM1.HISTJUMBOQueryetikettnr.AsString)
```

Sometimes I surprise myself with the stupid things I do ...

Comment: what is the real problem?

Comment: one thing which I do not understand, and is only halfway related 
what is the difference between these, why use first instead of second .
spStoredProcedure.Parameters.ParamByName('@OP').Value:='INS';
vs
spStoredProcedure.Parameters.ParamValues['@OP']:='INS';

Both work fine, the help does not explain why use one instead of other .

Comment: There is no real difference between ParambyName and ParamValues. It comes down to coding style. Which one do you like better?